# Graphql Apollo upload in Nestjs returns invalid value {}

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I tried adding an upload argument to a GraphQL endpoint using `graphql-upload`'s `GraphQLUpload` scalar:

```js
import { FileUpload, GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload'

@Mutation(() => Image, { nullable: true })
async addImage(@Args({name: 'image', type: () => GraphQLUpload}) image: FileUpload): Promise<Image | undefined> {
// do stuff...
}
```

And this worked initially. A few runs later however, and it started returning the following error:

```
"Variable \"$image\" got invalid value {}; Expected type Upload. Upload value invalid."
```

Tried testing with Insomnia client and curl:

```sh
curl localhost:8000/graphql \
  -F operations='{ "query": "mutation ($image: Upload!) { addImage(image: $image) { id } }", "variables": { "image": null } }'
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.image"] }'
  -F 0=@/path/to/image
```

Comment: @xadm thanks for the reply. The spec here: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec mentions these should be null, is this not the case?

Comment: it worked ... node.js errors/warnings? restart?

Comment: @xadm `GraphQLError: Upload value invalid. at GraphQLScalarType.parseValue (/path/to/project/nest/node_modules/graphql-upload/lib/GraphQLUpload.js:66:11)`. It worked for me initially (about an hour), then the error came and I'm not sure what changed if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little digging it appears that `apollo-server-core` automatically parses file uploads in the middleware with `graphql-upload` based on the request being a multi part form, rather than determining by scalar type name. So `graphql-upload` isn't necessarily needed as it's already integrated, but it's useful for getting the parsed type:

```js
import { Scalar } from '@nestjs/graphql'
import FileType from 'file-type'
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql'
import { FileUpload } from 'graphql-upload'
import { isUndefined } from 'lodash'

@Scalar('Upload')
export class Upload {
  description = 'File upload scalar type'

  async parseValue(value: Promise<FileUpload>) {
    const upload = await value
    const stream = upload.createReadStream()
    const fileType = await FileType.fromStream(stream)

    if (isUndefined(fileType)) throw new GraphQLError('Mime type is unknown.')

    if (fileType?.mime !== upload.mimetype)
      throw new GraphQLError('Mime type does not match file content.')

    return upload
  }
}
```

**Update 01/02/2021**

Still struggle with this today. Some great answers here, but they no longer work for me. Issue is if I throw an error in `parseValue` it 'hangs'. The below solution works the best for me by resolving the 'hanging' issue and still pushing the actual file through for usage (use case is `.csv` file):

```js
import { UnsupportedMediaTypeException } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Scalar } from '@nestjs/graphql'
import { ValueNode } from 'graphql'
import { FileUpload, GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload'

export type CSVParseProps = {
  file: FileUpload
  promise: Promise<FileUpload>
}

export type CSVUpload = Promise<FileUpload | Error>
export type CSVFile = FileUpload

@Scalar('CSV', () => CSV)
export class CSV {
  description = 'CSV upload type.'
  supportedFormats = ['text/csv']

  parseLiteral(arg: ValueNode) {
    const file = GraphQLUpload.parseLiteral(arg, (arg as any).value)

    if (
      file.kind === 'ObjectValue' &&
      typeof file.filename === 'string' &&
      typeof file.mimetype === 'string' &&
      typeof file.encoding === 'string' &&
      typeof file.createReadStream === 'function'
    )
      return Promise.resolve(file)

    return null
  }

  // If this is `async` then any error thrown
  // hangs and doesn't return to the user. However,
  // if a non-promise is returned it fails reading the
  // stream later. We can't evaluate the `sync`
  // version of the file either as there's a data race (it's not
  // always there). So we return the `Promise` version
  // for usage that gets parsed after return...
  parseValue(value: CSVParseProps) {
    return value.promise.then((file) => {
      if (!this.supportedFormats.includes(file.mimetype))
        return new UnsupportedMediaTypeException(
          `Unsupported file format. Supports: ${this.supportedFormats.join(
            ' '
          )}.`
        )

      return file
    })
  }

  serialize(value: unknown) {
    return GraphQLUpload.serialize(value)
  }
}
```

This on the `ArgsType`:

```js
@Field(() => CSV)
file!: CSVUpload
```

This in the resolver:

```js
// returns either the file or error to throw
const fileRes = await file

if (isError(fileRes)) throw fileRes
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further how did you get your mutation working? I'm running into the same error

Comment: Is your `apollo-server-core` package at latest? If so, it includes `graphql-upload` in it's dependencies and has the middleware handling file uploads already.

Answer (score 24):

Use `import {GraphQLUpload} from "apollo-server-express"`

not **import  GraphQLUpload from 'graphql-upload'**

[image]

Comment: Why this answer not at the top?!

Comment: I had issue just with the docker and this worked for me. you are from the future

Comment: apollo-server-express no longer includes `GraphQLUpload`.

Answer (score 11):

Based on @willsquire's answer, I realized that for some reason the Scalar decorator is not working for me, therefore I ended up replacing graphql-upload with the next snippet

```js
import * as FileType from 'file-type'
import { GraphQLError, GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql'
import { Readable } from 'stream'

export interface FileUpload {
  filename: string
  mimetype: string
  encoding: string
  createReadStream: () => Readable
}

export const GraphQLUpload = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Upload',
  description: 'The `Upload` scalar type represents a file upload.',
  async parseValue(value: Promise<FileUpload>): Promise<FileUpload> {
    const upload = await value
    const stream = upload.createReadStream()
    const fileType = await FileType.fromStream(stream)

    if (fileType?.mime !== upload.mimetype)
      throw new GraphQLError('Mime type does not match file content.')

    return upload
  },
  parseLiteral(ast): void {
    throw new GraphQLError('Upload literal unsupported.', ast)
  },
  serialize(): void {
    throw new GraphQLError('Upload serialization unsupported.')
  },
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply 
```@Mutation(() => File)
  async uploadFile(
    @Args({ name: 'input', type: () => GraphQLUpload }) fileInput: FileUpload,
  ): Promise<File> {
    const url = await this.filesService.create(fileInput)
    return { url, success: true }
  }
```
Where  GraphQLUpload and FileUpload are imported from my previous code and File type is just the schema that you are going to return

Comment: This errors for me when I upload a file: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at ReadStream.open"

Answer (score 3):

For me, solutions proposed here by @Yhozen and @Willsquire are a kind a workaround but not the true answer to the problem.

In my case, **the real problem was coming from** `graphql-upload`
I had it in my dependencies and it was creating the bug described in this stack.

By removing the dependence it solved the problem. As @willsquire commented, graphql-upload is already in apollo-server package, no need to import it in package.

Comment: It might be exposed now, but at the time the type wasn't exposed (i.e. `FileUpload `). Hence the dependency and import :)

Comment: Sure @willsquire. You’re comment from 12th Feb guide me. Thank you for that. After few hours trying to solve the issue, you gave me the rights tips!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use  the graphql-upload package, then you have to apply their Express middleware, and disable apollo server's internal upload module.

see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64659256/10404270

After that a mutation like this works for me:

```
import { GraphQLUpload, FileUpload } from "graphql-upload";

  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async docUpload(
    @Arg('userID') userid: number,
    @Arg('file', () => GraphQLUpload)
    file: FileUpload
  ) {
    const { filename, createReadStream } = file;
    console.log(userid, file, filename, createReadStream);
    return true
  }
```

Comment: Apollo Server no longer supports uploads out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is here:
https://dilushadasanayaka.medium.com/nestjs-file-upload-with-grapql-18289b9e32a2

Note: To test a file upload you must send correct format of the file. Graphql does not support file paths. such as:

```
{
    file: '/user/mim/desktop/t.txt'
}
```

and you must be sent complete file.