# Variable "$file" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, graphql, antd

I am using GraphQLClient from `graphql-request` to send requests to my server. I am trying to upload a file by doing the following:

```
const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors',
});
const source = gql`
    mutation uploadImage($file: Upload!) {
        uploadImage(file: $file)
    }
`;
const file: RcFile = SOME_FILE; // RcFile (from antd) extends File
await graphQLClient.request<{uploadImage: boolean}>(source, { file });
```

However, when I send a request to my server this way I get the following error:

```
GraphQLError: Variable \"$file\" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid
```

This is what my request looks like in the console:

```
operations: {
    "query":"\n mutation uploadProfileImage($file: Upload!){\n uploadProfileImage(file: $file)\n }\n",  
    "variables":{"file":null}
}
map: {"1":["variables.file"]}
1: (binary)
```

Has anyone else had this issue? I can't seem to upload a file to my backend.

Comment: console.log(file) ?

Comment: `File {
    uid: "rc-upload-1604388578610-2",
    name: "images.jpg",
    lastModified: 1604388587004,
    lastModifiedDate: Tue Nov 03 2020 01:29:47 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
    webkitRelativePath: "", 
    name: "images.jpg"
    size: 4040
    type: "image/jpeg"
    uid: "rc-upload-1604388578610-2"
    webkitRelativePath: ""`

Comment: does this server support graphql upload properly ? ... mutation should have return type/fields defined

Comment: I am using typegraphql and graphql-upload on my backend:
`@Mutation(() => Boolean) async uploadImage( @Arg('file', () => GraphQLUpload) upload: UploadType): Promise<boolean> { ... }`

Comment: more like ... is it working using postman?

Comment: It seems to be happening on postman as well! `"Variable \"$file\" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid."`. I tried changing ApolloServer to have { uploads: false } in it's configuration and now I get `POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting the uploads option to false in the `ApolloServer` configuration.

```
new ApolloServer({ schema, context, uploads: false })
```

And then using the `graphqlUploadExpress()` middleware from `graphql-upload`.

```
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000, maxFiles: 10 }));
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who runs into the same issue I did

Comment: I'm trying the same thing but get the error: "POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?". Did you run into that?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on ApolloClient that you used.

1- If used import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client' must be used "**createUploadLink**" instead of "**createHttpLink** "means,

```
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client'
const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: httpEndpoint,
})
```

2- if used createApolloClient, exact this package:

```
import { createApolloClient, restartWebsockets } from 'vue-cli-plugin-apollo/graphql-client'
const { apolloClient, wsClient } = createApolloClient({
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...options,
  })
``
You do not need to set anything and Upload work complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `ApolloServer` implementation described in the accepted answer (and to clarify @Masoud 's answer), make sure you also have the following client implementation using `apollo-upload-client`:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: createUploadLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
  }),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition, try to make sure `csrfPrevention` is not set to true in your ApolloServer config

```js
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    csrfPrevention: false, // if this is set to true, uploads will fail
    uploads: false,
    cache: "bounded",
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true })],
  });
```