# "GraphQLError: Variable \"$file\" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid."

Tags: graphql, upload, postman, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to upload a file to graphql server with postman. But I'm getting this error(Variable $file got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid). Please help me to resolve this. I'm using type-graphql to build the API.

just use nestjs + typeorm + graphql

```
operations: {"query":"mutation($file: Upload!) {\n  uploadFile(file: $file)\n}"}

map: {"0": ["variables.file"]}

0: file.png
```

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable "$file" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658321/variable-file-got-invalid-value-upload-value-invalid)

Comment: Did you find a solution